# Mailchimp and CiviCRM: possible integration using custom contact fields?

Tags: email, integration, mailchimp

looking for some advice about a potential Mailchimp integration.

I've used the wonderful Mailchimp CiviCRM Extension and it works great, but I'm not sure it will work for a specific case I've got.

If I understand correctly, the Extension only uses the main contact email of each contact, and maps that to groups that are synched with Mailchimp lists.

But each contact profile in this use case includes additional custom contact fields containing names and emails (as an example, an organizational profile includes contact names/emails for different departments).

My questions:

-- Is there any way to synch these groups of custom fields to specific Mailchimp lists?

-- If not (as I suspect!), how would you approach such an implementation?  Create individual Civi contact entries for each of these subcontacts? Or is there a way to customize the Extension to use custom fields for synching?

The system in question is Joomla+CiviCRM at latest versions.

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in mailchimp extension ATM. But its possible via creating a extension that will extend mailchimp and use the sync api/function or altering the mailchimp extension itself.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for the info Pradeep....confirmed what I expected, but nice to know I wasn't missing something obvious.